# How do I submit a tag synonym?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I notice that Squillman has entered some tag [synonyms](https://serverfault.com/tags/synonyms) into the system that are [currently pending](https://serverfault.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=suggested).

How does one do this?

Comment: Bump, @all, please remember to occasionally check the pending link and vote.

Comment: @Zore, the problem with voting is that it's too hard to do lots at once :( It would be nice if the up/down votes were on the pending page itself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like it's kinda hidden.

according to [the one true meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57479/allowing-users-with-a-nominal-amount-of-rep-to-submit-possible-tag-synonyms-and-v) you need to go into the tag and then hit the info tab.

Comment: There can be only one...  Bah, screw that.  We got our own now!

Comment: @squillman ... completely tongue in cheek ... I say we have a party and kill all the ponies and unicorns :)

Comment: Hahaha :)  I don't know, Evan hung onto his pony for quite a while after April 1!  Re: tongue in cheek: I was with you.  Was playin' off of Highlander in the comment!